# How can I remove wireless network, Which is already stored in the system

Tags: networking

I am using elementary os 5.1.4 Hera version, In that, I am not getting the wireless network to forget option. In the previous version of elementary os wireless network forget option is there.

This is a bug... Please resolve this on high priority...

Comment: I do not see such an option too, but stackexchange is not a place for bugs - it is a community where people share information how things work or not. If you want to report a bug - file an issue into https://github.com/elementary into appropriate section.

Answer (score 8):

Use terminal and type sudo nmtui. There you will ne able to delete it.